# How are partition numbers (sda1, sda2, sda3, ...) determined?

Tags: partition, disk, gpt, mbr, partition-table

In my experience, partition numbers have nothing to do with the physical ordering on the disk. And a newly created partition tends to have a larger number.

How are partition numbers determined? Are they recorded on a special area of the disk?

I think that maybe it depends on whether GPT or MBR.

Comment: Does this anwer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320631/change-sda2-to-sda1

Comment: With MBR the 4 primary partitions are in the MBR or first sector of a drive. Logical partitions starting at 5, are a linked list. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record With gpt you have a primary partition table & backup partition table at end of drive. gpt(GUID) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table Both seem to assign partition numbers in the order you create the partitions. Changing numbers can be done, but usually creates major issues.